# Cleaner way to randomly get a string from multiple arrays with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Multiple arrays are automatically generated server side with no way of modifying it with the names: section1, section2, section3 so on and so forth. There is always a minimum of one value per array and a maximum of 50 in each array.

Example array list:

```
section1 = ['ABC100', 'ABC105', 'ABC209'];
section2 = ['ABC400', 'ABC705', 'ABC629'];
section3 = ['ABC176', 'ABC136', 'ABC279'];
```

I currently need to randomly select one value from each array and update an image src attribute. I do have access to the image HTML, so can change classes etc.

Current HTML example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img class="section1" src="">
    <img class="section2" src="">
    <img class="section3" src="">
</div>
```

My javascript and jQuery for randomly selecting a value from it's matching array and updating the image src is:

```
var $pathName = '/images/gallery/';
var $fileExtension = '.jpg';

var $section1R = section1[Math.floor(Math.random()*section1.length)];

var $section2R = section2[Math.floor(Math.random()*section2.length)];

var $section3R = section3[Math.floor(Math.random()*section3.length)];

$('.section1').attr('src', $pathName + $section1R + $fileExtension);
$('.section2').attr('src', $pathName + $section2R + $fileExtension);
$('.section3').attr('src', $pathName + $section3R + $fileExtension);
```

This seems really messy. Is there a way of making this cleaner without repeating so much code? I know it works, but I'd like to learn better ways of coding repeated functions.

Comment: Don't make a list of array variables, but an array of them that you can iterate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the arrays in an array:

```
var sections = [section1, section2, section3];
```

Then just pass a function to `attr` and use the index of the iteration to access the correct array:

```
$('#wrapper img').attr('src', function(index) {
    var section = sections[index];
    var value = section[Math.floor(Math.random() * section.length)];
    return $pathName + value + $fileExtension;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You might do this :

```
$('#wrapper img[class^=section]').attr('src', function(){
    var a = window[this.className];
    return $pathName + a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)]+$fileExtension;
});
```

But I'd advise against having all your variables in the global namespace. I would thus use an object or an array to hold them.

Note also that usually the convention is to start variable names with a `$` only when they hold a jQuery set. Here it's hard to know why you give them such names.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize it into a function because all three selections do the same. One way could be:

```
function rndElement(arrayElement)
{
   return arrayElement[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayElement.length)];
}

var $section1R = rndElement(section1);
```